# How double value is stored in JVM and how JVM read out its corresponding binary value from memory and cast it to decimal value?

Tags: jvm, double

We know that if a decimal value such as 2.4 to be store in JVM, it should be converted into binary value first. But for its convertion logic, it cannnot convert the exact value 2.4, instead, its converted binary value is approximately 2.3999999999999999.

```
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 2.4;
    System.out.println(d);
  }
}
```

I guess, JVM store this value in memory. But while `System.out.println(d);`, I think firstly it should get the binary value from memory, and then print it. I think what it get from memory is 2.3999999999999999, here it print out 2.4.

Can someone tell the difference here? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: does my answer need further clarification?

Comment: Sure. Thanks. By the way, while debugging in Intellij idea, if we double click a double variable to select it and check its value, we find that it also show 2.4. So I guess, Intellij idea also shows the nearest value over the true value, right?

Comment: I imagine that since intellij is written in Java they also use Double.toString to render doubles in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks. I think so, too.

Comment: Why do you think, `2.4` is not the “true value”? After all, you did initialize the variable with `2.4`. There wouldn’t be more truth in showing `2.3999999999999999`, as the actual “true” value is `2.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375`, which is not only impractical, it would also be confusing if the debugger showed the value differently than Java’s builtin string conversions. It’s very likely that it ends up at the same code anyway, but even if I implemented a Java debugger in a different programming language, I took care to show the value the same way as Java does.

Comment: @Holger. I initialize the variable with ``2.4``, I guess it is only something like string in .class file after compile. Whiling running, it will convert it into binary value, so the real value stored in memory is not equals to ``2.4`` any more. That's why ``2.4`` is not the true value.

Comment: No, this value is already converted at compile-time. That’s the whole point of it. There is no decimal number in the class file and neither at runtime, unless you tell the JVM to generate it, e.g. like with `System.out.println(d);`, which follows the rules described in the answer. There is no additional truth in an alternative algorithm to generate a decimal number. These are only interpretations of the bit pattern `0100000000000011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011`. You could also write `double d=0x1.3333333333333p1;` or `double d=Double.longBitsToDouble(0x4003333333333333L);`…

Comment: @Holger. Thanks for let me know that 2.4 is alreday in binanry format after compile in .class file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`println` uses `Double.toString` internally for converting a double to a string, which can then be printed.

The [`Double.toString` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) says the following:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a?
>   There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and
>   beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to
>   uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type
>   double. That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value
>   represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for
>   a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest
>   to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be
>   one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of d must
>   be 0.

The important part here is "as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double".

This means that as long as `2.4` is closer to the actual value in `d` than to any other possible double value, `2.4` will be printed.